# Prove that at least two are the same $p = b^c + a , q = a^b + c , r = c^a + b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes

Given  *a, b, c ∈ N*
 *p = b<sup>c</sup> + a , 

q = a<sup>b</sup> + c ,
 r = c<sup>a</sup> + b* 
 we know that p q r are primes. Prove that at least two of the p ,q ,r are the same.

***Edit:***
i have tried with contradiction method.I assumed all three p q r were not the same got 2 cases where i have 2 even numbers and one odd which is contadiction but that is dead end because after i can only get one even and two odd numbers which doesn't tell me anything

Comment: What efforts were made ?

Comment: p q r are primes just edited

Comment: well i tried with contradiction method.I assumed all three p q r were not the same got 2 cases where i have 2 even numbers and one odd which is contadiction but that is dead end

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions.

Comment: As you said, looking at their parities we get that one of the three numbers $p,q,r$ is even. But they are prime, so the even one must be $2$.  If you set one of them (it doesn't matter which) as $2$, what does that tell you about $a,b$ and $c$?

Comment: it tells me that one of the exponents must be 1 (since 2^1 is 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $a,b,c$ are positive integers and $p,q,r$ are prime numbers such that
\begin{align*}
p&=c^a+b\\[4pt]
q&=a^b+c\\[4pt]
r&=b^c+a\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

**Claim:**$\;$At least two of $p,q,r$ must be equal.

Suppose instead that $p,q,r$ are all distinct

If two of $p,q,r$ are even, those two primes must both be equal to $2$, contradiction.

Hence at most of one of $p.q.r$ is even.

Consider four cases . . .

**Case $(1)$:**$\;p$ is even and $q,r$ are both odd.
\begin{align*}
&
p\;\text{is even}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
p=2
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
b=a=1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
q=1+c\;\text{and}\;r=c+1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
q=r
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
contradiction.

**Case $(2)$:**$\;q$ is even and $p,r$ are both odd.
\begin{align*}
&
q\;\text{is even}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
q=2
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
a=c=1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
p=b+1\;\text{and}\;r=1+b
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
p=r
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
contradiction.

**Case $(3)$:**$\;r$ is even and $p,q$ are both odd.
\begin{align*}
&
r\;\text{is even}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
r=2
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
c=b=1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
p=1+a\;\text{and}\;q=a+1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
p=q
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
contradiction.

**Case $(4)$:**$\;p,q,r$ are all odd.

First suppose $a$ is even.

- Since $a$ is even and $p$ is odd, $b$ must be odd.

  Then since $b$ is odd and $r$ is odd, $c$ must be even.

  But then since $c$ is even and $q$ is odd, $a$ must be odd, contradiction.

Next suppose $a$ is odd.

- Since $a$ is odd and $p$ is odd, $b$ must be even.

  Then since $b$ is even and $r$ is odd, $c$ must be odd.

  But then since  $c$ is odd and $q$ is odd, $a$ must be even, contradiction.

Thus each of the four cases yields a contradiction.

It follows that $p,q,r$ cannot all be distinct, hence at least two of $p,q,r$ must be equal.

Comment: Clear as day! Thank you so much. :D

Answer (score 0):

Since $p$ is odd by definition (assuming it isn't equal to $2$), then either $a$ is odd and $b$ and $c$ are even, or vice-versa.

Suppose $a$ is odd and $b$ and $c$ are even. Then $q$ is odd, but $r$ is even. Since $r$ is prime, it must be equal to $2$. But $r=c^a+b$, and the only solutions to $c^a+b=2$ such that $a$ is odd and $b$ and $c$ are even is $a=a, b=2, c=0$. We now check to see whether these values result in $p$ and $q$ being prime:

$p=b^c+a=2^0+a=1+a$

$q=a^b+c=a^2+0=a^2$

As we can see, whatever the value of $a$, $q$ cannot be prime. It must therefore be the case that $a$ is even and that $b$ and $c$ are odd. So again we look at $r=c^a+b$. An odd number raised to an even number is odd and the sum of two odd numbers is even, meaning that $r$ must once again be equal to $2$. This time, the only solution is $a=0, b=1, c=c$. I have left $c$ as an indefinite value as *any* odd value of $c$ will satisfy this equation. We therefore turn our attention to $p$ and $q$:

$p=b^c+a = 1^c+0=1$

$q=a^b+c=0^1+c=c$

Okay, that's no good either. Since neither case — two odd and one even, or two even and one odd — results in all three of $p,q,r$ being prime, it must be that all three of $a,b,c$ are odd. If *that's* the case, then the only prime value any of $p,q,r$ can take is $2$, for which the solution is $a=b=c=1$

QED.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case where(a=b=c=0). In this scenario:

(p = 0^0 + 0 = 1)
(q = 0^0 + 0 = 1)
(r = 0^0 + 0 = 1)

Since all three expressions yield the same result when (a=b=c=0), our assumption that all three are distinct is false. Therefore, at least two of the expressions must be the same.

Comment: The variables $p,q,r$ are required to be primes, and the varables $a,b,c$ are assumed to be positive integers, so your example fails both of those requirements. But in any case, even if you repair those flaws. showing an example for which the hypothesis and conclusion are both true doesn't prove that the hypothesis implies the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Using parity, if $q,r$ are both odd,

Then $a $ odd $\implies c$ even $\implies b $ odd  $\implies b^c$ odd $\implies p$ even.

Also, $a$ even $\implies c$ odd $\implies b $ even $\implies b^c$ even $\implies p$ even.

So let $p = 2 = b^{c} + a \implies a = 1 \implies b = 1 \implies q = 1 + c$ and $r = 1 + c \implies q = r$.

If one of $q,r$ is even, then WLOG let $q = 2 \implies p = r$ from above.